# How to get a string value from Angular2 ng2Translate TranslateService method

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am just looking at [ng2Translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) so I can use it for localization in my `Ionic2 / Angular2` project. I have it set up and working, and get the correct values in markup when using according to the documentation...

```
 <div>{{myVal}}</div>
 <div>{{ 'COMMON.HELLO' | translate:{value: "world"} }}</div>
```

and my string values come through fine.

I now wanted to try and get some strings in code behind, and assign these to component variables, which I can then bind to in the markup, as in the following.

```
@Component({
 templateUrl: 'build/pages/sidemenu-page/sidemenu-page.html',
 pipes: [TranslatePipe]
 })
 export class SideMenuPage {
  public rootPage = SideMenuPage;

  public myVal: string;

  constructor(private menu: MenuController, private nav: NavController, private    tranlate: TranslateService){
    let temp = tranlate.get("MYTESTVAL");
    this.myVal = temp.first(); // <-- type error first does not return a string
  }
```

and then use it...

```
<div>{{myVal}}</div>
```

The `tranlate.get` returns an RxJs observable (which I am just starting to look at, I have not used them before) - and I just cannot see how to get the "raw string value" from it. Event the `first` still seems to return an observable.

Can anyone let me know how to get the string?

Comment: Try `this.myVal = temp;` and `{{myVar | async}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading on the RxJs, it looks like all I need to do it

```
temp.subscribe(x => this.myVal = x)
```

this certainly seem to work at any rate.

### Update

Even better, there is an instant method: `this.myVal = tranlate.instant("MYTESTVAL");`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/sidemenu-page/sidemenu-page.html',
  pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})
export class SideMenuPage {
  public rootPage = SideMenuPage;

  public myVal: string;
  public sub: any;

  constructor(private menu: MenuController, private nav: NavController, private tranlate: TranslateService){
    this.sub = tranlate.get("MYTESTVAL").subscribe(value=>this.myVal=value,error=>console.log(error));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```